# fractionally spaced channel equalizer code

Tags: digital-communications, equalization, fading-channel, equalizer, channel-estimation

I want to write a program in matlab for an adaptive fractionally spaced equalizer with lms algorithm.consider each packet with 150 bits that 25 first bits are pilot and used to train weights of the equalizer.consider the channel constant during sending each packet. number of equalizer taps is 10 . input rate of the equalizer is 6/Ts and output rate of the equalizer is 1/Ts or symbol rate. I searched a lot about fractionally spaced equalizer but I couldn't write the program.
Thank you for your help

Comment: Hi Mahtab! Questions for working code are off-topic here. Please explain what *signal processing problem* you have that you could not solve!